# Can isomorphism existence be proved via rank-nullity?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A student in my class mentioned his approach to proving isomorphism via the rank-nullity theorem rather than showing an inverse's existence. I didn't quite understand how, but perhaps someone here might be able to explain...

Comment: This is certainly possible, but could you provide some context?

Comment: I'm baffled as to how you thought entomology was on-topic here. Don't do something like that again.

Comment: Be more specific. What context are you looking for?

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick What was what problem?

Comment: Isomorphism of what?  What is the proposition whose proofs we are talking about?

Comment: $T:V\rightarrow W$ is an isomorphism... We are checking if $T$ is an isomorphism...

Comment: Under what assumptions?  Surely not _every_ $T: V \to W$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @TrevorWilson $V$ fdvs /$F$ and $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your cryptic response, but what if $T(x) = 0$ for every $x \in V$?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following is meant?

If $V,W$ are vector spaces over a field $K$ and $\dim(V)=\dim(W)<\infty$, and $f : V \to W$ is a linear map, then the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is an isomorphism
2. $f$ is injective (i.e. $\ker(f)=0$)
3. $f$ is surjective (i.e. $\mathrm{im}(f)=W$)

Proof: 1 => 2 and 1 => 3 are clear. If $f$ is injective, then $\dim(W)=\dim(V)=\dim(\ker(f))+\dim(\mathrm{im}(f))=\dim(\mathrm{im}(f))$ implies $\mathrm{im}(f)=W$, therefore $f$ is surjective. The same argument shows the converse. The rest is clear.

Comment: Wow! Everything is so **clear** now. Thanks! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism of vector spaces is a linear map $T:V \to W$ that is

- a monomorphism:  it's one-to-one
- an epimorphism:  it's onto

Now,

> **1.** $~~\rm{nullity}(T) = 0$ is equivalent to the map being
>   *one-to-one*, and
>
> **2.** $~~\rm{rank}(T) = \dim W$ is equivalent to the map being *onto*.

If you know that $\dim V = \dim W$, then by the **rank-nullity theorem**, either one of **1.** or **2.** suffices to conclude that $T$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: And if you know that $\dim V\ne\dim W$, rank-nullity shows the inexistence of isomorphisms.

Comment: You don't have to quote rank-nullity for that. It is trivial by the very definition of the dimension as the cardinality of a basis that isomorphic vector spaces have the same dimension.

Comment: It's true that dimensions being equal is enough to conclude that two vector spaces are isomorphic (that *an* isomorphism exists), but to be able to conclude that a *particular* map is an isomorphism, you need either full rank or zero nullity.